# My trackpad doesn't turn on after I turn it off, before that it works

Tags: trackpad

The trackpad on my ASUS laptop doesn't work after I press off and then on. Before I press off the first time it works well, afterwards it doesn't work even though the light indicator is on. This problem has happened to me since Ubuntu 10.04/Linux Mint 9/and now 10.10, it works fine on Win7, but I don't really want to boot there ;).

Comment: +1 for this issue, im having the same problem. Is there a solution to this? i dont really care if the off key doesnt work on the trackpad i just want to get my trackpad working again

Answer (score 3):

it is indeed a bug as discussed here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/546503

this is not a cure for the bug, but get your trackpad running again, run:

```
gconftool --type bool --set /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true
```

Answer (score 2):

Please file a bug. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting