# Trackpad has stopped working after pressing off key, how to reenable?

Tags: trackpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My trackpad doesn't turn on after I turn it off, before that it works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6424/my-trackpad-doesnt-turn-on-after-i-turn-it-off-before-that-it-works)

further to this issue:

[My trackpad doesn't turn on after I turn it off, before that it works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6424/my-trackpad-doesnt-turn-on-after-i-turn-it-off-before-that-it-works)

im also exhibiting the same problem, but there doesnt appear to be a solution stated on that question. As my comment states, i dont really care if i can't use the off key (if it is a bug ill just wait till a fix appears) on my trackpad, but to not have a trackpad at all is a bit of a showstopper, is there anyway to re enable a dead trackpad? nb im using ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is indeed a bug as discussed here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/546503

this is not a cure for the bug, but get your trackpad running again, run:

```
gconftool --type bool --set /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true
```